# Zeppelin throwing java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver when running a demo pyspark script on AWS

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run a demo spark script to read data from AWS RDS Instance of PostgreSQL.

Trying to use Zeppelin notebook as it comes with AWS to run my demo spark script given below.

But when i try to read the data, Zeppelin is throwing the following exception => "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" when running the Pyspark script on AWS

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import os
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('Pyspark Postgresql Demo') \
    .config("spark.jars", "/path/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/path/postgresql-42.2.5.jar') \
    .config('spark.driver.extraLibraryPath', '/path/postgresql-42.2.5.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
    
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--driver-class-path /path/postgresql-42.2.5.jar --jars /path/postgresql-42.2.5.jar'

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://test-rocky.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XX-XXXX-X.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test_db_schema") \
    .option("dbtable", 'test_table_name') \
    .option("user", "test_username") \
    .option("password", "test_password") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```

This throws the exception :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o439.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried connecting to the Postgresql DB using a local PGAdmin. The credentials are working fine, i'm able to query the table "test_table_name", although there are no rows in the table.

Why am i getting this exception ? Am i setting it wrong ? Is my spark jar config wrong ? I have ssh'ed into the driver linux machine and checked whether the jar exists in the right path. But it still throws the "No suitable driver" exception.

Any help is appreciated.

***Question Updated :***

Based on other posts and answers, i changed the code from :-

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://test-rocky.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XX-XXXX-X.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test_db_schema") \
    .option("dbtable", 'test_table_name') \
    .option("user", "test_username") \
    .option("password", "test_password") \
    .load()
```

to :

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://test-rocky.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XX-XXXX-X.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test_db_schema") \
    .option("dbtable", 'test_table_name') \
    .option("user", "test_username") \
    .option("password", "test_password") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()
```

But now, it throws another exception :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o183.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

***Updated Question :***

Tried using this code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/path/to/postgresql.jar').getOrCreate()
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://host/dbname'
properties = {'user': 'username', 'password': 'pwd'}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table='tablename', properties=properties)
```

With no change in the output :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o183.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Update again :

I could not get it to work on Zeppelin notebook on AWS, but it worked when i ssh'ed into the master EC2 node and used

```
pyspark --driver-class-path /spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar --jars /spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar
```

This is the code that worked for me :-

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
jar_dir = "~/path/postgresql-42.2.20.jar"
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', jar_dir).getOrCreate()
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://XXXXXXXXXXX.rds.amazonaws.com/db_name'
properties = {'user': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table='table_name', properties=properties)
df.printSchema()
```

Comment: I've had the same trouble with spark code suffers from deterioration from lack of maintenance between it and sql.  You've picked software that doesn't play nice together and that's lead you to finding bugs between these software.  A good exercise.